# What was the average price of Škoda Favorit in Poland around 1991?

Tags: poland, automobiles

I am looking for the average price of a Škoda Favorit in Poland around 1991 (1992 would be appreciated as well)
I cannot find this information online anywhere.

I have found price of this car and other cars in the year 1994 [here](http://www.zlomnik.pl/index.php/2014/04/17/ceny-nowych-samochodow-w-polsce-w-1994-r/) (although the article is in Polish) if anybody is interested.

I wonder how much the prices have changed over those 3 years.

I am having trouble finding this information and it's an interesting time period because it was right after the fall of communism in 1989.

Comment: Some people want to close this for being trivial. Perhaps you could motivate the question more?

Comment: Hmm. I feel like if it was trivial it would already have an answer. I guess a more difficult question would be to find prices of all common cars but i was interested in this one in particular. I think if the question would be more challenging it would be even less likely to get an answer

Comment: I didn't mean the question was easy to answer. I meant that the three close voters probably think this question isn't of inherent historical interest. So "motivating" the question just means explaining to us all why the question is interesting. (Note that I did not vote to close! I just hate seeing good questions get closed, so this was some unsolicited advice.)

Comment: You could probably buy something like [this](http://allegro.pl/katalog-samochody-swiata-1991-i5287483861.html). Maybe there is a scanned one somewhere on chomikuj.pl. I remember there were prices. I even have one at home (I don't remember which year, I will see in the evening, CET, Warsaw time). Also, please note that there were many older cars and prices can vary depending of the year of production.